# Wrapping SignalR in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, signalr

**The Background:**

So, I have a bit of a weird situation (it's kind of out my control, actually).

We've been building an HTML5 JavaScript rich Single Page Application -- it doesn't even use Razor, it's all HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

On the backend, we use WebAPI, and SignalR.

We've been told recently, that the backend will need to be on a different server, and behind a firewall without public access.

We're allowed to deploy new WCF services to an existing front-facing SharePoint 2010 server (running .NET 3.5!!). -- The plan is that the backend services will be IP restricted, and the only incoming access will be via the server hosting the WCF services...

Fine, for Web API, that's no big deal -- we just duplicate all the service's public end points in a WCF REST service, we make the call from the back end, and we pass back the results... (basically we will tunnel it).

But, for SignalR, things get pretty complicated.  Obviously, if we're going to tunnel like this, we lose Web Sockets -- that sucks but it's not the end of the world -- as long as we don't lose the long-polling and forever frame fallback methods and it works (regular polling isn't an option for us.)

**The Question:**

Is there a specific end point we can listen to long-polling / forever frame requests on and forward on to the backend? -- are there specific cookies that we will need to forward so that the backend knows who we are? -- any guidance on this?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build your own HTTP proxy.  Why not use an off-the-shelf HTTP Proxy server?

Comment: @JaredDykstra -- In a normal scenario that would be the right way to go -- unfortunately, our front end can't be allowed to talk directly to the backend (the HTTP proxy would just forward it on verbatim, and kind of defeat the purpose of the IP restriction enforcing that, right?) -- what we're building is a little more complicated than a proxy -- it has other requirements that I can't share due to NDA (unfortunately) -- but basically the "proxy"-like code needs to be running as part of the SharePoint site.